# MiKTeX spelling check red underline

Tags: miktex, spelling

I have MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit on a Windows 10, and I can't get the red underline in misspelled words to appear. I tried to install in different folders, but no success. If I right-click on a misspelled word it gives me the alternatives, but it shows no red underline.

Any suggestions?

Edit:
I use it with TeXWorks.

Comment: (1) welcome,  (2) Miktex does not do spellchecking, that is a part of your editor of which you have given us no details. Please update your question

Comment: random idea: try the 32-bit version

Comment: You need to install the spell checking files. Just Google "Texworks spellcheck", there should be several hits. It basically means downloading some file(s) from open office, unzip them (they are zip files with unusual file endings), and then copying two of those files into a special location for texworks. After which the spell checking for this language can be chosen I texworks

Comment: Mark, I tried installing 32-bit version, no luck.
daleif, the dictionaries are working because when I right-click on a misspelled word, it shows me the options, but the misspelled word is not red-underlined